# Typescript: Use Method Parameter in Subfunction

Tags: javascript, variables, methods, scope, typescript

I am not quite sure how to express my Problem in words so let me Show you some of my code:

```
class MyClass
{
    public Columns: MyCol[];

    public AddColumn(Header: string, Url: string)
    {
        Columns.Add(new MyCol(Header, function()
        {
            $.ajax(Url, ...);
        }));
    }
}

//Somewhere in the execution
var mc = new MyClass()
mc.AddColumn("col1", "myurl1");
mc.AddColumn("col2", "mycol2");

mc.Columns[0].CallFunction();
mc.Columns[1].CallFunction();
```

So what I expected was that it will ajax-call "myurl1" first and then "myurl2".
But what it does it calls "myurl2" twice.
Shouldn't the scope of the Url-Parameter be just inside the Method so it should work?

Greetings
Neokil

Comment: Why do you need an Array?, and what is CallFunction()?

Comment: `Columns.Add` is that really your code? Shouldn't it be `Columns.push`?

Comment: @RGraham even more, it should be `this.Columns.push`

Comment: there is nothing in your code called *myurl2*. Is it a typo in your question?

Comment: @RGraham its just some pseudo-code since the source is much more complex.

Comment: @Waog I'm sorry, in the line "mc.AddColumn("col2", "mycol2");" it should be called "myurl2" not "mycol2"

Comment: @user3044096 The Thing is, I want to be able to add multiple columns, each with its own URL. The Problem is, every column will have the URL of the column last added.

Answer (score 0):

### Use Lambda Expressions

You should use [Lambda Expressions](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#functions-lambdas-and-using-39this39) (written like `() => {...}`) instead of regular functions definitions (`function() {...}`) here. Lambda expressions are used to hand variables of an outer scope into the scope of inner functions.

In your case the content of `AddColumn` should look something like this (didn't try it out myself):

```
    Columns.Add(new MyCol(Header, () => {
        $.ajax(Url, ...);
    }));
```